# Why hiding one header section when click on button

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewsectionheader

I have one UITableView and it has also header section. Based on header section they have correspondent data.

> Each header section have one button which is clickable as user will
>   click on it it will expend the UITableView

[image]

> I am using below code for it

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
      let headerCell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("DashTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! DashTableViewCell
    headerCell.lblQueryType.text = queriesArray[section]
    headerCell.btnExpendable.addTarget(self, action: #selector(expendSection), for: .touchUpInside)
    headerCell.btnExpendable.tag = section
    return headerCell
}

@objc func expendSection(button: UIButton) {
    var indexPaths = [IndexPath]()
    let section = button.tag
    if button.tag == 0 {
        QueriesStructArray[section].isExpended = !QueriesStructArray[section].isExpended
        for row in QueriesStructArray.indices {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: section)
            indexPaths.append(indexPath)
        }
    } else if button.tag == 1 {
        MyQueriesStructArray[section].isExpended = !MyQueriesStructArray[section].isExpended
        for row in MyQueriesStructArray.indices {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: section)
            indexPaths.append(indexPath)
        }
    }
    if button.tag == 1 {
        if MyQueriesStructArray[section].isExpended == true {
          tblProjectDashBoard.deleteRows(at: indexPaths, with: .fade)
        } else {
            tblProjectDashBoard.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .fade)
        }
    }
    else if button.tag == 0 {
        if QueriesStructArray[section].isExpended == true {
        tblProjectDashBoard.deleteRows(at: indexPaths, with: .fade)
        } else {
            tblProjectDashBoard.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .fade)
        }
    }
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return queriesArray.count
}
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 40
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 {

        if QueriesStructArray[section].isExpended == true {
            return 0
        }
        return QueriesStructArray.count
    } else if section == 1 {
        if MyQueriesStructArray[section].isExpended == true {
            return 0
        } else {
        return MyQueriesStructArray.count
        }
      }
    return 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProjectDashTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? ProjectDashTableViewCell {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            cell.lblTitle.text = QueriesStructArray[indexPath.row].queries
            return cell
        } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
            cell.lblTitle.text = MyQueriesStructArray[indexPath.row].myQueries
            return cell
        }
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

> every thing is working fine but as I clicked on "Shared Queries"
>   button then "My Queries" section got hide which is wrong I am unable
>   to find the issue in code

[image]

Comment: got answer instead returning "headerCell" in viewForHeaderInSection it should return "headerCell.contentView" the solution of this issue